# How can I view permissions granted to Public

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a schema called Lookups within a SQL Azure database.

The Public database role has SELECT permissions granted on that Schema.

But how can I see this via a query? I've spent the last couple of hours searching the web, but have yet to find a query which will show me permissions granted to specific schemas and objects to the Public role.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All granted permissions are visible in `sys.database_permissions`, eg

```
create schema Lookups
go
grant select on schema::lookups to public
go

select schema_name(major_id) schema_name, permission_name, state_desc 
from sys.database_permissions p
where grantee_principal_id = user_id('Public')
and class_desc = 'SCHEMA'
```

outputs

```
schema_name     permission_name    state_desc
--------------- ------------------ ------------
Lookups         SELECT             GRANT
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks very much for that.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't have a chance to test it for Azure but I used this query

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work on Azure - it gives the error "Invalid object name 'sys.login_token'." Perhaps I should have mentioned that it's a contained database, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Third part of the query regarding {All Users} do not reference sys.login_token.

Comment: OK - I get that bit to work, thanks. But it still doesn't show that Public has permissions on any user-defined schemas. 
Don't know how I can post the results here in a comment, but it shows that Public has various EXECUTE permissions, on stored procs such as sp_helpdiagrams
 and sp_helpdiagramdefinition, plus on one scalar function (fn_diagramobjects)

Comment: @AndrewRichards "*Don't know how I can post the results here in a comment*" - Comments are only meant for asking for clarification. You can put any updates in your original Post, as needed.